# linux: how to wait for a process and file at the same time?

Tags: python, linux, asynchronous, select

I am trying to build an event loop in python, mostly for educational purposes. I am not interested in solutions involving asyncio or similar because my goal is really to learn about the low-level linux APIs.

For file-like objects (pipes, sockets, …) there are the select/poll/epoll system calls. In python, these are wrapped in the [selectors module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html). This is a simple loop that can wait for several files at the same time:

```py
file1 = open('/var/run/foo.sock')
file2 = open('/var/run/bar.sock')

with selectors.DefaultSelector() as selector:
    selector.register(file1, selectors.EVENT_READ)
    selector.register(file2, selectors.EVENT_READ)

    while True:
        for key, mask in selector.select():
            if key.fileobj == file1:
                handle_data(file1)
            else:
                handle_data(file2)
```

For proceeses there is the wait system call. In python this is wrapped in the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). This is the code to wait for a single process to terminate:

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/foo'])
proc.wait()
handle_data(proc)
```

How can I mix those two, or even wait for more than one process at a time.

Both `selector.select()` and `proc.wait()` will take a timeout, so we can turn this into a semi-busy loop:

```py
file1 = open('/var/run/foo.sock')
file2 = open('/var/run/bar.sock')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/foo'])
timeout = 1

with selectors.DefaultSelector() as selector:
    selector.register(file1, selectors.EVENT_READ)
    selector.register(file2, selectors.EVENT_READ)

    while True:
        for key, mask in selector.select(timeout):
            if key.fileobj == file1:
                handle_data(file1)
            else:
                handle_data(file2)

        if proc:
            try:
                proc.wait(timeout)
                handle_data(proc)
                proc = None
            except TimeoutExpired:
                pass
```

I guess there must be a better way. How is this usually done?

Comment: You could start a thread that waits on a file and send a message on a Queue when the file is ready. Then start a thread that does subprocesses and sends a message on a Queue when done. Then in the main code thread, just wait on the Queue for messages from either. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I found the relevant information when looking at the different implementations of [child watchers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-policy.html#asyncio.AbstractChildWatcher) in python's asyncio:

- You can call `os.waitpid()` in a separate thread and write to a pipe when it is done. The other end of that pipe can be added to the select loop. This approach seems to be the most common.
- You can write to a pipe when you receive `SIGCHLD` and again add the other end of that pipe to the select loop. Then you can call `process.poll()` to check which of the processes has terminated in O(n) time.
- `open_pidfd()` is exactly what I was looking for. It is the cleanest solution, but only available on Linux >= 5.3. This is probably the way to go if you do not have to care about portability.